# Copied file in C not working

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a program in C that receives a filepath as an argument in the command line and makes a copy of it. This is my source.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
     if (args != 2)
     {
          printf("Error: Wrong number of arguments.\n");
          printf("Enter the path of the file to be copied as the only argument.\n");
          system("PAUSE");
          return 1;
     }
     FILE *fsource;
     FILE *fshellcode;

     if((fsource = fopen(argv[1],"rb")) == NULL)
     {
          printf("Error: Could not open source file. Either the path is wrong or the file is corrupted.\n");
          system("PAUSE");
           return 2;
     }

     if((fshellcode = fopen("shellcode.exe","wb")) == NULL)
     {
          printf("Error: Could not create shellcode.exe file.\n");
          system("PAUSE");
          return 3;
     }

     char c;
     while ((c = fgetc(fsource) != EOF))
     {
         fputc(c,fshellcode);
     }
     fclose(fsource);
     fclise(fshellcode;
     return 0;
}
```

When I enter the path of a working exe as an argument the program properly creates the shellcode.exe and copies all the bytes from the source exe into it. When I try to execute the new exe thought I get the following error message:

```
The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running.
```

How is that possible when the source exe is running properly on my 64bit Windows 7 system?

Comment: `fclise(fshellcode;` is certainly wrong.  Cut and paste the _true_ code.

Comment: Files have attributes aside from their data.  Perhaps you need to also certain permissions.

Comment: the use of `fgetc()` to retrieve the source file, byte by byte and checking for EOF will not work correctly.   Suggest using: `fp = fopen() then, fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END) then, long bytesInFile = ftell( fp ) then, fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET ) then, in a loop: fread(), fwrite() until the total number of bytes transfered is equal to bytesInFile.  be sure to always check function returned values to catch any errors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One problem is that you need to declare

```
int c;
```

How could that make a difference?  Well, the first byte you read with the value 0xff (which will happen pretty soon in a binary file like an exe) might get sign-extended to -1 and look like EOF.  So you may not be copying the whole file.

And then the second problem is that you've got an amusing typo in

```
while ((c = fgetc(fsource) != EOF))
```

The precedence of `!=` is higher than `=`, so the compiler interprets this as

```
while (c = (fgetc(fsource) != EOF))
```

So as long as you read a non-EOF character, `c` gets set to 1.

What you wanted was

```
while ((c = (fgetc(fsource)) != EOF)
```

(Also, it won't make a difference, but you should use `getc` and `putc`.  Was there a reason you were using `fgetc` and `fputc`?)

Comment: The shellcode.exe is the same size as the source.exe, although I see what you mean. I declared c it as an int but I still get the same problem. I always thought that fgetc and fputc were the proper functions to use in file IO.

Comment: I'd prefer fgetc and fputc

Comment: @exophrenik `fgetc()` and `fputc()` are fine to use.

Comment: @exophrenik Updated this answer with your other problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was that typo in the EOF that broke the executable.

Comment: Using `getc()` and `putc()` may use a macro instead of a function call, which may improve the performance of the code.  Using `fgetc()` and `fputc()` ensures that you are making a function call for each I/O operation.  Whether that matters is up to you to decide and measure.

Answer (score 1):

- Use **while ((c = (fgetc(fsource)) != EOF)**
- In this first it will get the value from the file and compare with `EOF`, and if it is not `EOF` than copy into **Variable(c)** .
- Read [Operator precedence in c](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) .